# JAX-RS POST Method return null parameter value

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I have been googling this for like forever but no relevant answer. I'm posting a json object in my POST method but the parameter object return null value. GET is working fine

Below is my POST Method:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Parameter > postPayment(Parameter param){

    //Example param.getValue return null
    return getData(param);
}
```

The setters and getters

```
public class Parameter {

protected String name;
protected String value;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

The json request

{
  "name": "name 1",
  "value": "value 1"
}

Note: I am using JAX-RS on netbeans

Need your help please. Thank you

Comment: Was your problem solved ? If yes, please accept one of the below posted answer, which helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `MessageBodyReader` interface and inside `readFrom` method convert JSON to object using library of your choice.

Look at [this page](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter6/custom_marshalling.html) for details on how to implement and configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@Consumes` annotations

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)  // you can change this as per your requirement
public List<Parameter> postPayment(Parameter param){
  return param.getValue(); // return value 1
}
```